# Google Sites HTML Box isn't recognizing CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sites

So, I've searched around for a bit and found out that some of the CSS won't load in `editor` mode but will load in `previewer` mode, however, not all CSS is functioning properly and the Javascript is completely failing.

Here's some `html` and `javascript` I tried with the HTML Box:

```
  <table id="Killed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Buffalo</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count1"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Camels</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count2"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Cattle</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count3"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Chickens</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count4"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Ducks</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count5"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Goats</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count6"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Horses</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count7"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Pigs</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count8"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Sheep</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count9"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Turkeys</td>
        <td align="right">
          <span id="Kill_Count10"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table><br><br>



 <script>     
   window.addEventListener("load", function () {
   function Kill_Count(id,totalDeaths) {
     var deathsPerSecond = totalDeaths/365/24/60/60/4;
     var deaths = 0, result;
     var timer = 1;
     setInterval(function() {    
       deaths = deathsPerSecond*timer;     
       result = deaths.toFixed();
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
       timer++;
     }, 250);
   }

   var killnum = "23199336 1501799 301275455 49877536490 2676365000 402611664 5018470 1375940758 564785251 635382008";
   killnum = killnum.split(" ");
   for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
     var num = i-1;
     var temp = killnum[num];
     Kill_Count('Kill_Count'+i,Number(temp));
   }
 });
 </script>
```

What needs to be added?  Here's the website https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. I think I may have found a decent solution for you:

First off, Google's HTML Box is auto-generating new id tags for the ids you made. So, `id="Kill_Count1"` through `id="Kill_Count10"` is turning into something like `id="id_3___"`

The first thing I did was change all of the ids to Classes, all set to "Kill_Text":

```
<span class="Kill_Text"></span>
```

Next, I wrote some javascript code to collect the elements these classes were in and set their ids back to "Kill_Count1" and such like you had before:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("Kill_Text");
// Reset auto-generated ids to Kill_Count#
for (var j = 1; j <= spans.length; j++) {
    spans[j-1].id = ("Kill_Count" + j);
}
```

From there, your code worked just as expected.

**Side notes:**

- At first when I was trying to get javascript to run I had to save the code in the box, save again, then refresh the page. Hopefully this helps if you didn't know already :)
- Have you used Chrome developer tools? They are super useful when debugging web pages. [Ctl + Shift + I]
- Your code currently sets 10 timers doing pretty much the same actions on individual spans. It would be more efficient to have one timer doing 10 actions (1 on each span)

**For Reference:**

Here's the final code I used in the HTML box:

```
<table id="Killed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Buffalo</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Camels</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cattle</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chickens</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ducks</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Goats</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Horses</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pigs</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sheep</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Turkeys</td>
            <td align="right">
                <span class="Kill_Text"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function Kill_Count(id,totalDeaths) {
        var deathsPerSecond = totalDeaths/365/24/60/60/4;
        var deaths = 0, result;
        var timer = 1;
        setInterval(function() {    
            deaths = deathsPerSecond*timer;     
            result = deaths.toFixed();
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
            timer++;
        }, 250);
    }

    var killnum = "23199336 1501799 301275455 49877536490 2676365000 402611664 5018470 1375940758 564785251 635382008";
    killnum = killnum.split(" ");

    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("Kill_Text");

    // Reset auto-generated ids to Kill_Count#
    for (var j = 1; j <= spans.length; j++) {
        spans[j-1].id = ("Kill_Count" + j);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var num = i-1;
        var temp = killnum[num];
        Kill_Count('Kill_Count'+i,Number(temp));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting point on the interval, I rewrote my code so it only works with one interval, however, that one interval would need to loop through 70 lines of code every iteration given that I would need to reset the id's and totalDeaths value... with 10 intervals, the total number of lines processed on each iteration is 40, but I haven't looked that deeply into efficiency practices and I'm not entirely sure how taxing an interval would be, do you know?

Comment: Thank you so much on the refreshing the page tip, I wasn't aware you needed to do that, CSS is working 'better' now.

Comment: So I'm also having a different problem with getting GAS to work with the custom HTML, I would have just put everything within the Gadget, but for some stupid reason there are two scroll bars on the page now and I can't figure out how to remove the formatting, do you have any experience with this sort of thing?

Comment: Intervals: I'm not totally sure actually, but you should be fine either way. I don't think intervals are very taxing.
CSS: Awesome, Glad that helped!
GAS stuff: I don't have any experience with that. I'd recommend starting a new question for others to look at.